# Using VBA to copy and paste a table element from IE11

Tags: html, vba, element

I am trying to select elements and copy to my clipboard. I have successfully used similar code as below when there was an id, but for this table there doesn't seem to be an id to reference. Is there a way to use class name or some other way to select the table elements? I am just simply copy and pasting and don't want to do any looping if it can be avoided. When I go into the source html and hover over the class "grid grid-v2 " and "copy the element" and paste into excel it's the table I want and basic formatting. But my below code stops (location in code below) and I get run-time error 438:

> "Object doesn't support this property or method".

Any insight would be helpful

```
    Sub Macro2()
'
 Dim ieApp As InternetExplorer
 Dim ieDoc As Object
 Dim ieTable As Object
 Dim clip As DataObject

      Set ieApp = New InternetExplorer
       With ieApp
         .Visible = True
          End With

           '1st table retrieval
               ieApp.Navigate "http://www.cmegroup.com/trading/interest-
                   rates/countdown-to-fomc.html"
     Do While ieApp.Busy
        DoEvents
         Loop
  Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:04"))

Set ieDoc = ieApp.Document
Set ieTable = ieDoc.getElementsByClassName("grid grid-v2 ")
 'copy the tables html to the clipboard and paste to the sheet
 If Not ieTable Is Nothing Then
     Set clip = New DataObject
     clip.SetText ieTable.outerHtml 'I GET THE ERROR HERE
     clip.PutInClipboard
     ActiveSheet.Select
     Range("N125").Select
     Selection.PasteSpecial "Unicode Text"
 End If

  ieApp.Quit
   Set ieApp = Nothing

    Range("N123").Select

     '
     End Sub
```

Comment: Apparently the `ieTable` object does not have an `outerHtml` property.

Comment: FWIW instead of `Select`ing and then doing `Selection.PasteSpecial`, you should be doing `ActiveSheet.Range("N125").PasteSpecial`. Avoid `Select`, avoid `Activate`, and avoid `Selection`.

Comment: Yea I guess I should have been more clear. I realize the ieTable lacks the property to grab outerhtml and any other text. I'm wondering how to use "getelement" to get the outerhtml of the table I want, whether it's classname, id, tag name or some other way to copy the elements outerhtml. Thus far I have tried different ways and all have failed

Comment: @kyleb, ieTable is a collection. ieTable(0).outerHTML should work.